# Catch "each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" issue without using list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new at the React and don't know how to tackle this issue.

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Track`.
    at Artist (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1425:5)
    at Track (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3933:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Album_page (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5851:67)
    at RenderedRoute (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:317876:5)
    at Routes (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:318298:5)
    at Router (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:318236:15)
    at BrowserRouter (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:316568:5)
    at div
    at div
    at App (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:208:73)
    at Provider (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:313931:5)
    at div
```

It had me in stitches because I don't have any lists in the Artist component.

Artist comp:

```
const Artist = ({artistName, classes, addAfter, styles}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    function goToArtistPage(e) {
        navigate('/artist/' + artistName)
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    return (
        <span className={classes} onClick={goToArtistPage} style={styles}><u className={" artist"}
                                                                             style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>{artistName}</u>{addAfter}</span>
    )
}
export default Artist;
```

Comment: It's telling you about the "Track" component. I'm guessing you're mapping over data in there but aren't adding keys in the right place.

Comment: can you add the code of your Track component?

Comment: Yep, @Andy was right. I didn't notice that I'm mapping my data and it turns to the list of Artists. There is the part of Track comp code:

`track.artistNames.map( (e,i) => { return (<Artist artistName={e} classes={"album_artist"}/>);})`

Comment: @nik231002 All you need to do is add a key to the `<Artist>` component props. If all the artist names are unique you could use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning says to look at the "render" method in the "Track" component. Perhaps lists are used there. Apparently you are using list of Artists in the Track component